# QRegExp not working as expected

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` and want to select specific text in it using `QRegExp`

here is example of a text block:

```
Block1 = Foo1 {
     bla bla bla;
     bla bla bla;
}
```

I need to select starting from `=` till `}` given the sub-string `Foo1`

Here is my code:

```
QString name = "Foo1";
QString pattern = "[\\=][\\s]" + name + "[\\s][\\{](^\\})*[\\}]";
//pattern = "[\=][\s]Foo1[\s][\{](^\})*[\}]"
```

and these lines for selection:

```
this->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
this->document()->find(QRegExp(pattern));
```

and strangely, this select only `Foo1` not

```
= Foo1 {
     bla bla bla;
     bla bla bla;
}
```

Comment: Which version of qregexp are you using ?

Comment: This piece of code `QRegExp(pattern)` means I'm using the default version `QRegExp::RegExp`

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

Here is your final regex for `Foo1`:

```
[\=][\s]Foo1[\s][\{](^\})*[\}]
```

And here is what `QRegExp` understands:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### The solution

So here is what you should tell it:

```
=\s*Foo1\s*{[^}]+}
```

and what it'll understand:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### There is more...

- In the solution I admit that no `}` can appear in the code. Otherwise, regex are not well suited for handling this case. If this happens in your context, you should rely on parser instead of regexes.
- Use [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to visualize your regex.

Comment: well, I tried part of your pattern `=\s*Foo1\s*{` and it doesn't make any match (as it should), while this pattern `\=\s*Foo1\s*\{` matches with `= Foo1 {` so the "\" escape character is needed I guess, however this pattern `\=\s*Foo1\s*\{[^\}]+\}` still doesn't make any match. While in debuggex.com it makes the correct match !!

Comment: Also I noticed there are several Pattern Syntax for QRegExp but not sure which one I should use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#PatternSyntax-enum